Why the max_iter parameter has no effect (or the contrary effect) on this logistic regression?
I have this code that does logistic regression
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay, roc_auc_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

from loguru import logger

data_path="../data/creditcard.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(data_path)
df=df.drop("Time",axis=1)
print(df.head())
print(f"Shape: {df.shape}")

# Randomly sampling 50% of all the normal data points
# in the data frame and picking out all of the anomalies from the data
# frame as separate data frames. 
normal=df[df.Class==0].sample(frac=0.5,random_state=2020).reset_index(drop=True)
anomaly=df[df.Class==1]

print(f"Normal: {normal.shape}")
print(f"Anomalies: {anomaly.shape}")

# split the normal and anomaly sets into train-test

normal_train,normal_test=train_test_split(normal,test_size=0.2,random_state=2020)
anomaly_train,anomaly_test=train_test_split(anomaly,test_size=0.2,random_state=2020)

# From there split train into train validate

normal_train,normal_validate=train_test_split(normal_train,test_size=0.25,random_state=2020)
anomaly_train,anomaly_validate=train_test_split(anomaly_train,test_size=0.25,random_state=2020)

# Create the whole sets

x_train =pd.concat((normal_train,anomaly_train))
x_test=pd.concat((normal_test,anomaly_test))
x_validate=pd.concat((normal_validate, anomaly_validate))

y_train=np.array(x_train["Class"])
y_test=np.array(x_test["Class"])
y_validate=np.array(x_validate["Class"])

x_train=x_train.drop("Class",axis=1)
x_test=x_test.drop("Class",axis=1)
x_validate=x_validate.drop("Class",axis=1)

print("Training sets:\nx_train: {} \ny_train: {}".format(x_train.shape, y_train.shape))
print("Testing sets:\nx_test: {} \ny_test: {}".format(x_test.shape, y_test.shape))
print("Validation sets:\nx_validate: {} \ny_validate: {}".format(x_validate.shape, y_validate.shape))

# Scale the data

scaler= StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(pd.concat((normal,anomaly)).drop("Class",axis=1))

x_train=scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test=scaler.transform(x_test)
x_validate=scaler.transform(x_validate)


def train(sk_model,x_train,y_train):
    sk_model=sk_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    
    train_acc=sk_model.score(x_train,y_train)
    
    logger.info(f"Train Accuracy: {train_acc:.3%}")

def evaluate(sk_model,x_test,y_test):
    eval_acc=sk_model.score(x_test,y_test)
    
    preds=sk_model.predict(x_test)
    auc_score=roc_auc_score(y_test,preds)

    
    print(f"Auc Score: {auc_score:.3%}")
    print(f"Eval Accuracy: {eval_acc:.3%}")
    

    roc_plot = RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(sk_model, x_test, y_test, name='Scikit-learn ROC Curve')

    
    plt.savefig("sklearn_roc_plot.png")
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
    
    conf_matrix=confusion_matrix(y_test, preds)
    ax=sns.heatmap(conf_matrix,annot=True,fmt='g')
    ax.invert_xaxis()
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    plt.ylabel('Actual')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
    plt.savefig("sklearn_conf_matrix.png")
    


sk_model= LogisticRegression(random_state=None, max_iter=400, solver='newton-cg')
# sk_model= LogisticRegression(random_state=None, max_iter=1, solver='newton-cg')

train(sk_model,x_train,y_train)
evaluate(sk_model,x_test,y_test)

using as data the Credit Card Fraud detection from here (in case to reproduce the results I am going to talk about)
The thing is that as you see we have
sk_model= LogisticRegression(random_state=None, max_iter=400, solver='newton-cg')

with that I got
2024-11-13 16:56:34.087 | INFO     | __main__:train:84 - Train Accuracy: 99.894%
Auc Score: 85.341%
Eval Accuracy: 99.874%

but if I change it to
sk_model= LogisticRegression(random_state=None, max_iter=10, solver='newton-cg')

I get the same results!
and to be extreme if I change it to
sk_model= LogisticRegression(random_state=None, max_iter=1, solver='newton-cg')

I get the expected warning
optimize.py:318: ConvergenceWarning: newton-cg failed to converge at loss = 0.1314439039348997. Increase the number of iterations.

but then I get better results!
2024-11-13 16:58:03.127 | INFO     | __main__:train:84 - Train Accuracy: 99.897%
Auc Score: 86.858%
Eval Accuracy: 99.888%

Why is this happening? I struggle to understand the concept of max_iter in this situation, (I have tried a purely python logistic regression with gradient descent and I kind of understand that in that situation) . Can someone clarify why this is happening?

I think it's related with accuracy.
The accuracy of a model is a metric that measures the proportion of correct predictions (both true positives and true negatives) made by the model out of all the predictions made, the equation likes:
Accuracy= (TP+TN) / (TP+TN+FP+FN)

As in credit.csv, most of labels (the column"Class") are 0 (only 492 of 280k rows are 1, others are all 0), which means model will be easier to give a very high acc, for example, just predict all output as 0 without model, the acc will be bigger than 99%.
Instead of acc, if we care more about positive part, we may use precision/recall, like below:
Precision = TP / (TP+FP)

Recall= TP / (TP+FN)


That was a fair assumption but I added precision and recall precision = precision_score(y_tests, preeds)  recall=recall_score(y_tests,preds) and still with 1 iteration, the results were better!

I modified the number of data for the label 0 and something interesting happened. If we take 0.1 instead of 0.5 of the normal data, and we reduce the max_iter then the recall goes down as expected from 82 to 52% The precision though still increases.

Hi @KansaiRobot, there is a trade-off between precision and recall, for example, if model predicts all values as 1, recall will always be 100% but precision may be low, so sometimes we will check F1 score (but that depends on your business scenario, some scenarios ask high recall and some may not)
